# How to strip blank lines in Mustache

Tags: java, json, mustache

Here is my Mustache template

```
   {{ word-1 }}
   {{ word-2 }}
   {{ word-3 }}
   {{ word-4 }}
   {{ word-5 }}
```

Here is my data json.

```
   {
    word-1: "How ",
    word-3: "Yes",
    word-5: "Nice"
   }
```

This creates:

```
How

Yes

Nice
```

How can I remove the blank lines in 2 and 4th lines and get the output like this using Mustache

```
   How
   Yes
   Nice
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [JMustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache) and [JStachio](https://github.com/jstachio/jstachio) (however JStachio cannot handle raw JSON) which are two Java mustache implementations that follow the standalone whitespace tag rules. **mustache.java** does not really follow these rules so your mileage may vary with that implementation!

```
        {{#word-1}}
        {{.}}
        {{/word-1}}
        {{#word-2}}
        {{.}}
        {{/word-2}}
        {{#word-3}}
        {{.}}
        {{/word-3}}
        {{#word-4}}
        {{.}}
        {{/word-4}}
        {{#word-5}}
        {{.}}
        {{/word-5}}
```

The "." is the implicit operator. It means use the current context. I believe handlebars mostly follows the standalone rules as well so this should work with [Handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java) however I did not test it.